# PyCharm startup failure

Tags: java, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

My PyCharm fails to startup after a reboot of system updates, it simply disappears after showing the splash screen.

When I tried to start it from command line, it shows following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.3\bin>pycharm.bat
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m; support was removed in 8.0

Start Failed: Internal error. Please report to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:83)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.isUnderDarcula(UIUtil.java:1295)
        at com.intellij.ui.JBColor.<clinit>(JBColor.java:34)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:232)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:71)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 36 incompatible with Text-specific LCD contrast key
        at java.awt.RenderingHints.put(RenderingHints.java:1075)
        at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopProperties.getDesktopAAHints(WDesktopProperties.java:312)
        at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.getDesktopAAHints(WToolkit.java:1035)
        at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getDesktopFontHints(SunToolkit.java:1848)
        at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopProperties.getProperties(WDesktopProperties.java:249)
        at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.lazilyInitWProps(WToolkit.java:911)
        at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.lazilyLoadDesktopProperty(WToolkit.java:900)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.getDesktopProperty(Toolkit.java:1803)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.<clinit>(UIManager.java:380)
        ... 10 more


Also, an UI exception occurred on attempt to show above message:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.swing.UIManager
        at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.updateUI(JTextComponent.java:338)
        at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.<init>(JTextComponent.java:312)
        at javax.swing.JEditorPane.<init>(JEditorPane.java:199)
        at javax.swing.JTextPane.<init>(JTextPane.java:90)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:231)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:217)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:86)
```

Noticed that it says "incompatible with Text-specific LCD contrast key", I started trying various display settings in my PC, and finally found that if I turn off "ClearType", it will be able to startup successfully.

How can I fix it without turning off ClearType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally found out the reason. There is a setting in registry that might be read by PyCharm, and then causes it crash:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\FontSmoothingGamma

I manually added this key a while ago, trying to improve ClearType text displaying, as referring to [this link](http://tweaks.com/windows/39124/fine-tune-cleartype-settings/).

After deleting this key, PyCharm can be started with ClearType enabled.